# Formatando nome de um arquivo com vários dígitos, iniciando com 0

Tags: javascript

Tenho que enviar um arquivo para um servidor de uma financeira, lá eles aceitam o arquivo se ele tiver o nome formatado de forma correta.

As regras para formatação são:

20190615-000000001.csv

Onde a primeira parte é a data em que o arquivo foi gerado, e a segunda parte é Número Sequencial do Arquivo formatado com 9 dígitos (este número deve evoluir de 1 em 1 para cada arquivo gerado).

O problema é, que quando gero um inteiro (porque ele precisa ser incrementado), e depois transformo em string para ir para o nome do arquivo, ele printa somente um dígito 0, tenho que printar todos.

Quero saber como faço para printar todos os dígitos de 0.

Comment: Para reabrir a pergunta coloque o fragmento de código que gera esse comportamento. De ler a pergunta eu imagino varias possibilidades, então fica impossível dar uma resposta sendo um tiro no escuro acertar a sua situação.